# Scrollview not scrolling to the top in a linear layout

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a fairly simple scrollview that is not scrolling all the way to the top of the screen when i scroll up.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.surreall.matchit"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout2"
    >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/board"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:baselineAligned="false"

            >     
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            >

            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>

            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card4"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>

            </LinearLayout>  
       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card5"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>

            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card6"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
           <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card7"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card8"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout> 
       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card9"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card10"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card11"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card12"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card13"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card14"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card15"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card16"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card17"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card18"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card19"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card20"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card21"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card22"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card23"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card24"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card25"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card26"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card27"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card28"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card29"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card30"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card31"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>
            <com.surreall.logo.SquareButton         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"          
                android:layout_weight="1"  >        
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card32"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"          
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                /> </com.surreall.logo.SquareButton>       
            </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout> 
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Looks like this]

Comment: show me  layout xml file completely

Comment: where is your scroll view in layout

Comment: check out this http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/01/scrollview-and-horizontalscrollview.html

Comment: set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your scrollview

Comment: i added 'android:fillViewport="true"' to the scrollview but undesired behavior remains.

Answer (score 10):

Hi I had the same problem, and after investigation I have found the solution, and in your XML code I can see that you are doing the same mistake in layout.

The problem is that you are setting the ScrollView child (LinearLayout) layout gravity to center. Remove this line and it should work for you.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"   //remove this line
```

Comment: What to set to make the layout center and full scrollable in scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are setting height as 0dp for linear layout parent. it should also wrap_content only make the changes and test it again.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // changed to wrap content
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:baselineAligned="false"

        >
```

It should work hopefully ... ok  you try with this change also to parent layout

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.surreall.matchit"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_content"         // changed to match_parent
android:layout_height="match_parent"         // changed to match parent
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id="@+id/main_layout2"
>
```

Comment: i am new to this scrollview stuff, i think copied that code from another project.  i made the change to the line you mentioned but the behavior is the same :?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in your layout: remove topmost `LinearLayout`, `ScrollView` should contain only one direct child with `layout_height="match_parent"`, so if you want to make the trick with weights you need to do it inside a LinearLayout that would be single child of ScrollView.